# Extruding and aligning on an existing face

Tags: faces, edges, extrude

I was wondering if there is a way to extrude such that it aligns on an existing face.

I've also included an image below since this is probably quite a vague description.

So what I would like is:
Extruding the yellow edge (on the X-axis only, which can be done by using the 'X' hotkey), such that it aligns on the purple face. I.e. one of the edges of the extrude is on the purple face.
[image: Model]

Since I'm new to blender (and 3D modelling in general) I'd love to hear if my entire approach is odd, wrong, or otherwise inefficient!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is edge going away from the viewer marked in yellow, i.e. the edge you want to extrude and align with purple-marked face is perpendicular to that face (how I see that from your description). How do you expect to align extrusion by edge?  In any case if you enable snapping, choose element to snap to as Edge and while extruding by X axis hover over proper edge it will be aligned by X axis.

Comment: @MrZak Ah I totally missed the snap to edge/face/vertex feature! While the snapping works differently than what I'd expect when extruding **on a specific axis**, I was eventually able to extrude the yellow edge (not the yellow arrow) to the purple face. Thanks for your help!